# Focus event not firing via Javascript in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Since upgrading to the latest Chrome version 34.0.1847.116, the focus event does not seem to be firing when calling

```
myinput.focus()
```

in Javascript.

This works fine in Chrome 33.0.1750.154.

test.html

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<input id="test_box" onfocus="alert('focused');" />
</body>
</html>
```

From the console:

```
document.getElementById('test_box').focus();
```

No alert in Chrome 34.

Any ideas? Is this a bug? Is there a workaround to fire the event?

Comment: Works for me. I avoided using `alert` for [my test case](http://jsbin.com/labubofe/1) ([source](http://jsbin.com/labubofe/1/edit)) because `alert` mucks about with focus. Tested with Chrome 34.0.1847.116 on Windows, I saw both the message saying I was about to focus, and the message from the `onfocus` attribute.

Comment: I have possibly related issue, downgraded to chrome 33 and the issues are gone.. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23100816/webdriverjs-protractor-focus-issues-make-tests-failing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The focus event will fire once you unfocus the Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: Did this behavior change? In Chrome v33, it changes focus from the console to the browser window when the event is fired and shows the alert.

Comment: I think it did, and this behaviour is the same in chrome canary, so I'm guessing it's either a bug that hasn't been reported yet or it was intentional.

Comment: is it true that it is more than "unfocusing" the console?  say if you switch to the Element tab and click on an element and therefore unfocused the console, it won't fire still.

Comment: @動靜能量 you are correct; the dev tools have to be unfocused, I have edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is actually a bug or bug fix for Chrome v34 if v33 doesn't show the same behavior. (it is due to typing the statement in, in the Console).

If you try http://fiddle.jshell.net/aQ5n6/7/show/

and go to the Console, and type in

```
document.getElementById('test_box').focus();
```

it won't alert because the focus is still in the Console... but as soon as you click on the content of the HTML doc (such as any empty space), then it will fire the alert.  It looks like when the focus is not actually on the input element (when focus is still on the Console), then the event is not fired.

Answer (score 1):

My  Version of **Google Chrome** is `34.0.1847.116`

working here [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx3BJ/1/)

```
<input id="test_box" onfocus="alert('focused');" />
```

Advice: Check your console for error or warning.